# How to cast a list of strings to mixed data types

Tags: python, string

I have a list of filenames, and based on a given regular expression, I extract an ID-Tuple. However, that produces strings. The actual ID is a combination of strings and numbers, and I want to cast it to the correct datatype. What's the best way to handle this?

I've considered two opions:

### Evaluation with ast.literal_eval

As a builtin, it's well tested and more general then what I could reasonably produce. However, it may actually be too general, and may produce something like a `None` or a bool. It's not an issue with my current data, but it needs to be considered for future proofing.

EDIT: Useing literal_eval doesn't work, since something like '02' is not a valid Python expression.

### Saving the specifications

Currently, the regular expression is saved as a string. That file could also contain a specification of how each capture group should be interpreted.

A very basic version would be to just list the datatype (string, int, float) and then go through them something like this:

```
for i, spec in enumerate(specifications):
    if spec == 'int':
        ID[i] = int(ID[i])
    elif spec == 'float':
        ID[i] = float(ID[i])
    elif spec == 'string':
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Incorrect Specification {spec} at index {i}')
```

But that seems like it invite human errors in handling the extra specification, and it introduces extra complexity.

I haven't got any experience on this front, so I don't know what the pitfalls are. What's the best approach here?

EDIT:
A filename might be something like `"FOR_Set2_CREE_1.79_0010APC.aver.dat"`
which gets transformed through a regular expression into the list of strings `["FOR", "2", "CREE", "1.79", "10"]`.
It then needs to be cast to `["FOR", 2, "CREE", 1.79, 10]`.

I don't have any control over what the ID's look like, so this can vary.

Comment: write please input string and those specifications

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output examples

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: @accdias I've got two options right in the post. I'm not sure what else you mean by "What did you try?"

Comment: Two options but no code demonstrating them. Read the articles, with special attention to ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The following function will do the job (works for the example you have provided), though no guarantees on being efficient or minimal:

(current timings: `42.8 µs ± 4.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`)

```py
import re

def func(s):
    # Split on '_'
    l = s.split('_')
    # Split on '.'
    l = [x.split('.') if not x.replace('.','',1).isdigit() else float(x) for x in l]
    # Unroll any nested list
    l = [x[0] if type(x)==list and len(x)==1 else x for x in l]
    l2 = list()
    for i in l:
        if type(i)==list:
            for j in i:
                l2.append(j)
        else:
            l2.append(i)
    l = l2
    print('Final shortlist for matching: {}'.format(l))
    # Perform regex based filtering
    l2 = list()
    for x in l:
        if type(x)==str:
            pat1 = r'([A-Z]*)([a-z]*)(\d+)'
            pat2 = r'[A-Z]+'
            
            m1 = re.match(pat1, x)
            m2 = re.match(pat2, x)

            if m1 is not None:
                l2.append(int(m1.group(3)))
            elif m2 is not None:
                l2.append(m2.group(0))
        else:
            l2.append(x)

    print('Required terms: {}'.format(l2))

s = 'FOR_Set2_CREE_1.79_0010APC.aver.dat'

func(s)
```

The output from the above code:

```bash
Final shortlist for matching: ['FOR', 'Set2', 'CREE', 1.79, '0010APC', 'aver', 'dat']
Required terms: ['FOR', 2, 'CREE', 1.79, 10]
```